# I want the Keyboard to remain on the screen while the Textfiled is removed or hidden Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have chat application in which when I record a voice message I hide the textfield and show the timer at the place of the textfield. Now when textfield get removed from the screen it also remove the keyboard from the screen. Due to which my voice message button move to the bottom of screen. I don't want to remove the keyboard when textfield get hidden just like whatsapp when we record the message It didn't hide the keyboard.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep keyboard open you need to keep focus on textfield. So if you want to hide a textfield you need to wrap it into a container with 0 height, for example.